# manufacturing debris inside carbon fork steerer tube

Tags: carbon, carbon-fork

I bought a 90mm compression plug so it would extend about 30mm into the bike's head-tube.  But when the carbon steerer tube was cut to desired length, the compression plug could only be inserted to 75mm depth. When I looked inside the tube, there was some immovable debris down inside it, apparently from the manufacturing process. I can't clearly make out what it is.  Is that a normal thing with carbon forks?  The obstruction begins about 9cm above the fork's crown.

[image: desired depth]

[image: partially inserted]

[image: freeze-frame image of debris]

Comment: These are most likely bladder remains, totally normal.

Comment: Just smack it in there. It looks to be mostly just excess resin. If you have a suitably sized drill bit, that might be more elegant.

Comment: What is the material? Epoxy?  Carbon fiber?

Comment: @Tim The yellow crud is epoxy, are there appears to be a few sheets of carbon that didn’t adhere properly as well. Removing them is fine because they weren’t contributing to the strength anyways.

Comment: I'd suggest using a suitably-sized round wooden dowell to push the excess down, rather than using a drill which could scratch things up.

Comment: @Criggie It is not "pushable" with moderate force. It's really stuck in place there. But I take your point about scratching or abrading the inner wall.  I might have found a plug that's just a tad shorter.

Comment: @Tim ok sounds like a fun task.  You might find that a piece of brass rod will work as a "push" stick and cope with hammering.  Additionally, a cheap bore-scope camera up the other side might provide a good view - they're cheap now-days, mine was sub $15 and uses a phone as display.